# cannot retrieve uilabel from an array

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad

I have an array of UILabels , but i couldn't use that UILabel from an array. Below is my code

```
for (int b=0; b<ObjIQuestions.m_muteArrOptions.count; b++)
        {

           UILabel* Optionlabel=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(LabelXaxis, 0, (FrameWidth/ObjIQuestions.m_muteArrOptions.count), 50)];
            IstructOptions *ObjOptions=[ObjIQuestions.m_muteArrOptions objectAtIndex:b];
            Optionlabel.text=ObjOptions.m_strNameEn;
            Optionlabel.numberOfLines=0;
            NSString* cleanedQnString = [appdelegate.HomePageStyle.m_strTopbarColor stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"#" withString:@""];
            //Optionlabel.textColor=[self colorWithHexString:@"F75454"];
            Optionlabel.textColor=[self colorWithHexString:cleanedQnString];
            Optionlabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana" size:12];
            Optionlabel.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentCenter;
            LabelXaxis=LabelXaxis+(FrameWidth/ObjIQuestions.m_muteArrOptions.count);
            [self.m_ArrQnOptionLabels addObject:Optionlabel];
        }
```

My array is not empty.
But i can't retrieve UILable instance using the below code.AddSubView is not working.
optionlabel gets a UILabel.

```
UILabel* Optionlabel=(UILabel *)[self.m_ArrQnOptionLabels objectAtIndex:0];
[cell.m_CtrlViewCompartment addSubview:Optionlabel];
```

Comment: m_ArrQnOptionLabels variable is constructed?

Comment: Ya, it has initialized and have uilabel instances, but the problem is cannot retrive it from the array

Comment: "cannot retrive" means `UILabel* Optionlabel=` is nil? Or you can not `addSubView`

Comment: UILabel* Optionlabel= is not null, but not a uilabel instance

Comment: Check NSLog(@"%@",self.m_ArrQnOptionLabels);

Comment: Can you print log after getting UILabel? Can you setBackGround for this UILabel and addSubView and check.

Comment: Have you allocated and initialised `self.m_ArrQnOptionLabels` as an NSMutableArray somewhere?

Comment: "<UILabel: 0x102c93a0; frame = (0 0; 72.2222 50); text = '7-Highly Satisfied'; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x102c9450>>",
    "<UILabel: 0x102cbaf0; frame = (72.2222 0; 72.2222 50); text = '6'; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x102cbba0>>",
    "<UILabel: 0x102cc080; frame = (144.444 0; 72.2222 50); text = '5'; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x102cc130>>",
    "<UILabel: 0x102cc3f0; frame = (216.667 0; 72.2222 50); text = '4'; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x102cc4a0>>",

Comment: option label has a label instance, i think the addsubview not working..

Comment: what is this `cell.m_CtrlViewCompartment`, UIVIew ??

Comment: Can you show your entire `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and check that cell.m_CtrlViewCompartment isn't nil

Answer (score 0):

The code should works fine , hopefully you might not initialised the `self.m_ArrQnOptionLabels`.

alloc and init the Array :

```
self.m_ArrQnOptionLabels  = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init]; // before using it
```